# Issue with method to calculate and display

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, try-catch

I'm having an issue with a programming assignment. The teacher assigned us something like the following:

Get input from the user about the total of a purchase and the amount they submitted, then call a single method from the main routine that calculates and displays the results (where the results are the change the user gets back in hundred dollar bills, fifty dollar bills, etc.

I have workable code for this problem, but I know I'm not fulfilling the requirements.  I also have a "gut feeling" that there's a better way to write the code so that it isn't so bulky.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the code I do have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Change
{
    class Change
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize variables
            double costOfPurchase = 0;
            double amountSubmitted = 0;
            double hundredDollarBills = 0;
            double fiftyDollarBills = 0;
            double twentyDollarBills = 0;
            double fiveDollarBills = 0;
            double quarters = 0;
            double nickles = 0;
            double pennies = 0;

            //Set up try catch for errors from user input
            try
            {
                //Get the cost of a sale
                Console.Write("Enter the total cost of your purchase: ");
                costOfPurchase = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (costOfPurchase < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The cost of your purchase cannot be a negative value.");
                }

                //Get the amount submitted to pay for the sale
                Console.Write("Enter the amount submitted: ");
                amountSubmitted = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

               if (costOfPurchase > amountSubmitted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have not submitted enough money.");
                }

                //Call a method to calculate and display the change due
                calculateChangeDue(costOfPurchase, amountSubmitted, out hundredDollarBills, out fiftyDollarBills, out twentyDollarBills, out fiveDollarBills, out quarters, out nickles, out pennies);

                Console.WriteLine(hundredDollarBills + " Hundred(s)");
                Console.WriteLine(fiftyDollarBills + " Fifty");
                Console.WriteLine(twentyDollarBills + " Twenty(s)");
                Console.WriteLine(fiveDollarBills + " Five");
                Console.WriteLine(quarters + " Quarter(s)");
                Console.WriteLine(nickles + " Nickle");
                Console.WriteLine(pennies + " Penny(s)");

                //Keep the console open in debug mode
                Console.Write("Press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred.");
                Console.WriteLine("The eror was: {0}", e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        //Method to calculate and display the change due
        private static void calculateChangeDue(double costOfPurchase, double amountSubmitted, out double hundredDollarBills, out double fiftyDollarBills, out double twentyDollarBills, out double fiveDollarBills, out double quarters, out double nickles, out double pennies)
        {
            //Initialize variables
            double changeDue = 0;
            double remainingChange = 0;

            //Calculate the change due
            changeDue = amountSubmitted - costOfPurchase;

            remainingChange = changeDue % 100;
            hundredDollarBills = (changeDue / 100) - (remainingChange / 100);

            fiftyDollarBills = (remainingChange / 50) - ((remainingChange % 50) / 50);
            remainingChange = remainingChange % 50;

            twentyDollarBills = (remainingChange / 20) - ((remainingChange % 20) / 20);
            remainingChange = remainingChange % 20;

            fiveDollarBills = (remainingChange / 5) - ((remainingChange % 5) / 5);
            remainingChange = remainingChange % 5;

            quarters = (remainingChange / 0.25) - ((remainingChange % 0.25) / 0.25);
            remainingChange = remainingChange % 0.25;

            nickles = (remainingChange / 0.05) - ((remainingChange % 0.05) / 0.05);
            remainingChange = remainingChange % 0.05;

            pennies = (remainingChange / 0.01) - ((remainingChange % 0.01) / 0.01);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code work or are you just asking for a CodeReview?

Comment: If the user enters a negative number for the total cost of the purchase, you'll display an error but the program will continue without stopping. Same with the amount submitted. I'm guessing this is invalid behavior.

Comment: if you are calculating and assigning the values in your `calculateChangeDue` method technically you don't need do declare the params as `out` variables since you already have initialized them at the top.. also to make your code cleaner I would read up on how to use the `string.Format` method when calling all of your Console.WriteLine also use the debugger to test for `Exception Handling and Negative values`

Comment: This question does not indicate how the requirements are not fulfilled, so it is hard to know what is being asked here. It ought to be closed for now, but of course it can be edited at any point in the future.